# Is it possible to set a default value for a parameter of a function in Dart?

Tags: dart

Like in JS, we can define default values like,

```
function location(lat = 20, lng = 20) {}
```

Can we set such default values like lat and lng in Dart? If yes, how? If no, why?

Answer (score 1):

You can set default values on [optional parameters](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters).

```
// optional positional parameters
location([num lat = 20, num lat = 20]) {}
// optional named parameters
location({num lat = 20, num lat = 20}) {}
```

Note that the default values must be compile-time constants.